# Make a functions run in sequence [Node JS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have these 2 fonctions that one run inside the other and second is using the output of the fisrt one (list).

What I want is to run in sequences. Can you help please?

```
gm_scrape.search_link(request, function(list){
    gm_scrape.fetch_profiles(list, function(profiles, request){
        console.log("the profil is "+profiles);
     });
});
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: These are running in sequence.  First `gm_scrape.search_link()` runs and then when it finishes, it calls its callback and then `gm_scrape.fetch_profiles()` runs in that callback.  What exact problem are you having that you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is to use Promises

```
gm_scrape.search_link(request).then(function(list){

    return gm_scrape.fetch_profiles(list);

}).then(function(profiles){

    console.log("the profil is "+profiles);

}).catch(function(err){ console.warn(err); });

gm_scrape.search_link = function(request){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        // async call...
        .onsuccess: resolve(list)
        .onfailure: reject(err)

    })
}

gm_scrape.fetch_profiles = function(list){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        // async call...
        .onsuccess: resolve(profiles)
        .onfailure: reject(err)

    })
}
```

Sorry I was kind of abbreviating for readability. This is an example of a Promise with an ajax call

```
gm_scrape.search_link = function(req){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: req.url,
            data: req.data
        }).success(function successCallback(list) {
            console.log(list);
            resolve(list);
        }).error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: I was just typing "use promises" nice answer!

Comment: thank you, I got this error      .onsuccess: resolve(list)
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: I was abbr some stuff, because Promises can be used to resolve(return) result from any async call like a db query or something

Answer (score 0):

While the example you provided in your question(as implied by the comment from jfriend00) is running in sequence. If you're trying to avoid the "pyramid of death" promises are a great way to do that as suggested by "Steven Kaspar".

However there are other common methods for doing the same thing. One of the other common ways to tackle this is using [caolan/async's](https://github.com/caolan/async) Waterfall method:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
    gm_scrape.search_link(request, function(list){
      callback(null, list);
    });
  },
  function(callback) {
    gm_scrape.fetch_profiles(list, function(profiles, request){
        callback(null, profiles);
     });
  }
], function(err, result) {
  console.log("the profile is ", result);
});
```

However if this might not make sense unless you have 3-4 callbacks embedded. Promises are probably a better design pattern overall, where as this solution is more geared towards an existing code base without promises where you need a way to organize a long series of tasks that depend on the results of the last, where callbacks would be messy and hard to manage. This might also be an easier solution if promises aren't available for your module and you don't want to spend time wrapping it(since these callback break promisify helpers provided by most promise modules).

Comment: thanks!, but I have this issue : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in line 89

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake copying and pasting, I also have no way to test since I'm not sure what the `gm_scrape` method does.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I would like to just add that you can use a simple callback function for this.

A very simple example:

```js
function first(next = null) {
  console.log('First')
  if (next) {
    next()
  }
}

function second() {
    console.log('Second')
}

first(second)
```